# Spring @Qualifer not working with Bean implementing multiple interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a bean which implements two interfaces. Below is my code-

```
@Qualifier("A")
interface InterfaceA {
    method a()
}

@Qualifier("B")
interface InterfaceB {
   method b()
}

public class ClassC implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
   method a(){}
   method b(){}
}
```

When I inject my bean in some other class, say

```
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("A")
    private InterfaceA a;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("B")
    private InterfaceA b;
  
}
```

I get below error whether I use Qualifier or not

UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name a... nosuchbeandefinitionexception

Comment: What is your goal here ? why are you trying to inject interfaces ? what exactly is the behaviour you're expecting ?

Comment: I want to call respective method of Interface A or B by injecting Interface A or B with or without @Qualifier. But when I try injecting with or without qualifier, it throws above-mentioned exception

Comment: you can't call a method of an interface unless you provide an implementation, and hence the bean created in the Spring container should be of the implementation of the interface not the interface itself. see the answer of @Ismail below.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `@Qualifier` annotation, we can eliminate the issue of which bean needs to be injected. So it is used with `@Component` annotation above classes, not interfaces.

In your case, you have just one class `ClassC` that implements two interfaces `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`.

So to resolve the issue, you need to add `@Component` to `ClassC`:

```
@Component
public class ClassC implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
   method a(){}
   method b(){}
}
```

And finally, you should remove all `@Qualifier` annotations, from `MyClass` and `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`.

Take look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) to know more about how to use `@Qualifier`.

Answer (score 0):

@Component is missing on your class C. Also make sure your component scan covers the package in which class C is present.